# Pillow on Heroku doesn't work

Tags: django, heroku, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I'm developing an application with Django1.4.3 and Pillow2.0.0.

I have a form to upload image file.
After resizing and cropping posted image file,
I want to save the image file, but error occur.

In django's local test server, error doesn't occur and work well,
but in Heroku, error occur.

Would you tell me some advice?
The code receiving posted image is below.
In addition, I use S3boto and django-storage.

```py
def edit_photo(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            # save posted image as UserProfile.image temporarily
            posted_photo = request.FILES['posted_photo']
            file_content = ContentFile(posted_photo.read())
            profile = request.user.get_profile()
            temp_filename = "new_file_"+str(profile.id)+"_"+posted_photo.name
            profile.image.save(temp_filename, file_content)

            # read posted file
            data = profile.image.read()
            im = Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(data))

            # crop posted image
            cropping_box = (10, 10, 300, 300)
            photo = photo.crop(cropping_box)
            photo_comp = photo.resize((230, 230), Image.ANTIALIAS)

            # save the image
            thum = StringIO.StringIO()
            photo_comp.save(thum, "png")
            profile.image.save("saved_image_"+str(profile.id)+".png",ContentFile(thum.getvalue()))

            # delete temporary image
            default_storage.delete("faces/"+temp_filename)

            return redirect('../')
```

---

And Error message is like this.

```
    TypeError at /manage/edit_photo
    function takes at most 4 arguments (6 given)
    Request Method: POST
    Request URL:    http://hogehoge.herokuapp.com/manage/edit_photo
    Django Version: 1.4.3
    Exception Type: TypeError
    Exception Value:    
    function takes at most 4 arguments (6 given)
    Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in _getencoder, line 395
    Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
    Python Version: 2.7.4
    Python Path:    
    ['/app',
     '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg',
     '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-1.11.0.55/newrelic/bootstrap',
     '/app',
     '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python27.zip',
     '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7',
     '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
     '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
     '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
     '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
     '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
     '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL',
     '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info']
```

---

```
    /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                            response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /app/movie_manager/views.py in edit_photo
                photo_comp.save(thum, "png") ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in save
                save_handler(self, fp, filename) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py in _save
        ImageFile._save(im, _idat(fp, chunk), [("zip", (0,0)+im.size, 0, rawmode)]) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py in _save
                e = Image._getencoder(im.mode, e, a, im.encoderconfig) ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in _getencoder
            return encoder(mode, *args + extra) ...
    ▶ Local vars
```

Comment: Solved! Downgraded Pillow from 2.0 to 1.7.8., it worked. Probably Python 2 vs 3 problem.

Comment: I was about to say - you must be doing something wrong - there's no good reason here for why it would work locally and not remotely.  Instead of changing your version of Pillow, why don't you change the version of [Python on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes)?  You should always aim for parity between the two environments.

Comment: I had a problem with Pillow + heroku; removing "distribute" from my setup.py fixed it

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who finds this problem...

This `TypeError` can occur when PIL and Pillow are installed simultaneously (perhaps inadvertently due to hidden package requirements). You'll need to uninstall *both* PIL and Pillow and reinstall just the one you want.